# Laravel 5 - Load views blade file from storage folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is it possible to load views from `storage` folder instead from `resources\views`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you have a couple of choices.

---

## 1. Add another path to your view config file

Open up `config/view.php` and add your new path to the `paths` array:

```
'paths' => [
    storage_path(),
    realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
],
```

Laravel will return whichever view that matches first, so be sure to sort the paths accordingly.

---

## 2. Add a view namespace

Open up `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` and add your new view namespace:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(storage_path(), 'custom_name');
}
```

With this you can access the views with a prefix like `custom_name`:

```
return view('custom_name::home');
```

Comment: Is there any other way instead of changing path in config, like using method in view's object? For example, view->method('path/to/view')

Comment: you want particular controller or method you want separate view folder(path)??

Comment: I have updated my answer with more information. Hope this answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Just config your view.php file like this

```
<?php

return
     ['paths' => [realpath(base_path('storage/views')),],

      'compiled' => realpath(storage_path('framework/views')),
];
?>
```