# How to load blade view from public folder

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I have blade view page which i wanted to show from public directory.As I have used `MailChimp` mail for sending email from my application and in `godaddy` server the mail page couldn't load the style properly as MailChimp mostly used `cdn` .

So i need to keep the blade view to public directory..How to i load the page inside mail function ?

```
public function build()
    { 
          return $this->from('support@abn-news.com', 'AbnNews')
            ->subject('Account Verification')
            ->view('emails.activation');  // Here i  need to load the view
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Load views blade file from storage folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373644/laravel-5-load-views-blade-file-from-storage-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper method `view()` to get the html content of a view in laravel. i.e

```
$activation_view = view('emails.activation');
```

Then use it as you wish...